# Adding two action listeners to a button does not seem to work

Tags: java, swing

I have the simple following code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ComeOnListener(jTextArea1));
button.addActionListener(new ComeOnListener(jTextArea2));
```

ComeOnListener is implemented as a private class (it was somehow syntactically confusing trying to implement it as anonymous) and it appends "Come on!" on the text area it receives as parameter. Nevertheless, it is only appending it on jTextArea2, completely ignoring jTextArea1. The listener goes as follow:

```
private class ComeOnListener implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea auxTextArea;

    public ComeOnListener(JTextArea jta) {

        auxTextArea = jta;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        auxTextArea.append("¡Come on!");
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


}
```

Could someone please tell me what's going on?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this is going to be a bug not contained in presented snippet.

Comment: Is this a custom button?  I thought you called the setOnClickListener() to register a listener to a button.

Comment: @johncarl Think again .. you register an `ActionListener` to a `JButton`, as clearly shown in the [Swing button tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: @Robin, thanks, I was stuck in an Android context. hehe

Answer (score 3):

As always, you should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) . Here is a working piece of code showing the wanted functionality

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AppendTextArea {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = createUI();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
  private static JFrame createUI(){
    JFrame result = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
    JTextArea firstArea = new JTextArea( 30, 30 );
    JTextArea secondArea = new JTextArea( 30,30 );
    JButton appendButton = new JButton( "Append" );
    appendButton.addActionListener( new ComeOnListener( firstArea ) );
    appendButton.addActionListener( new ComeOnListener( secondArea ) );

    result.add( firstArea, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    result.add( secondArea, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    result.add( appendButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    return result;
  }
  private static class ComeOnListener implements ActionListener {
    private final JTextArea auxTextArea;
    public ComeOnListener(JTextArea jta) {
      auxTextArea = jta;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      auxTextArea.append("Come on!");
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the code you posted is just copied into this snippet and works as expected. Most likely the problem is located elsewhere in your code.

Comment: *"Most likely the problem is located elsewhere in your code."*  +1